# Quais são todos os tipo de teclado e Inputs nativo que existe no iPad iOS 8?

Tags: ios, mobile, teclado

Preciso fazer uma mapeamento de todos os tipos de teclado que existe no iPad iOS8. Preciso saber quais são todas as maneiras de Inputar dados no Ipad. Como consigo isso!?

Comment: São basicamente estes que estão listados [aqui](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIKeyboardType).

Comment: Olá Pedro. Eu removi a tag [tag:ux] da questão porque ela não me parece relacionada.

Comment: @PauloRodrigues Por que você não oferece uma resposta, incluindo nela o código do link postado? Assim, ela potencialmente vai ser útil para outras pessoas (mesmo que o link fique fora do ar), e você ganha a merecida reputação. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira acontece que eu não tenho certeza, por isso joguei a resposta assim para que ele possa dizer se realmente é isso (já que a pergunta é somente sobre iPad), daí a resposta seria bem extensa pois são 11 opções, daí cada uma delas seria necessário ao menos traduzir para que fique claro. Enfim, foi mesmo questão de dúvida em relação à pergunta e tempo para elaborar uma resposta completa.